# A five-minute walk away the rebels have turned - meaning

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/confusion-over-rival-claims-control-donetsk-185927751.html

> Unfortunately for Taruta -- a billionaire oligarch appointed by Kiev to run the restive region following the ouster of pro-Kremlin president Viktor Yanukovych in February -- he was being forced to talk to journalists from a meeting room in a luxury hotel.
>   **A five-minute walk away the rebels have turned** what should be his office on the top floor of the region's barricaded administration building into the headquarters of their self-declared state.

I don't understand what this part means: **a five-minute walk away the rebels have turned what...**.

Comment: 'A five minute walk away' means: A short distance, equivalent to how far a person can normally walk in five minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that not far away (five-minute walk away), they *changed* ([turned into](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/turn-into?q=turn%20into)) what should be his office into the headquarters of their self-declared state.

A five-minute walk away the rebels have **turned** what should be his office on the top floor of the region's barricaded administration building **into** the headquarters of their self-declared state.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is badly formed and punctuated.  When a sentence starts with a phrase such as "A five-minute walk away," the phrase serves as a modifier further describing the word or word phrase immediately following the comma.  In this case it seems to indicate that the rebels are a five-minute walk away.  Doubtless the writer meant to say that it was Taruta's former office, now the headquarters of the rebels' self-declared state, that was a five-minute walk away.

The phrasal verb "turned into" is equivalent to the word "transformed."